# Method to check whether any vector is the solutions of an Over determined system of Linear equations or not.

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a system of linear equations $A*x<=b$ which is an overdetermined system as $rank(A)<rank(A|b)$. 
As this system has infinitely many solutions, my problem requires identification whether a particular vector $x$ satisfies these linear set of equations.

What I got from inspecting a 2-D problem is that these equations make a space between 2 lines intersecting at a point and all the points falling in the space are the solution of the equation.

Now I need a fast method to check whether a vector point is under the space or not and also I would like to exploit the sparsity of the matrix $A$.

Note: Dimensions of my actual problem is very high and I am using MATLAB for the work.